# How to SELECT an ID linked to its row?

Tags: sql

I have to get some datas with sql queries.

The thing is that one of my column needs to use the id of its own row to return then only 1 element so I guess I need a subrequest that returns only 1 row with the id of my row ?

But I tried and nothing is working. Here the `NAF` is my id :

```
SELECT 
    GAMME.GA_NBHR 
FROM 
    GAMME 
WHERE 
    GAMME.GA_DES LIKE 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU' 
    AND GAMME.NAF = (SELECT A.NAF FROM AFFAIRE A WHERE A.NAF = NAF)

SELECT 
    AFFAIRE.NAF 
FROM 
    AFFAIRE 
WHERE 
    AFFAIRE.NAF = (SELECT a.NAF FROM Affaire a WHERE a.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF)


GAMME.GACLEUNIK = (SELECT G.GACLEUNIK 
                   FROM GAMME G, AFFAIRE A 
                   WHERE A.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF)

SELECT 
    GAMME.GA_NBHR 
FROM 
    GAMME, AFFAIRE 
WHERE 
    GAMME.GA_DES LIKE 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU' 
    AND GAMME.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF 
    AND NAF = (SELECT NAF FROM AFFAIRE A WHERE A.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF)
ORDER BY 
    NAF
```

What I want is like if the NAF of the row = 1 it sends into my cell this query

```
SELECT GAMME.GA_NBHR 
FROM GAMME, AFFAIRE 
WHERE GAMME.GA_DES LIKE 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU' 
  AND GAMME.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF 
  AND AFFAIRE.NAF = 1
```

If the NAF of the row = 2 then

```
SELECT GAMME.GA_NBHR 
FROM GAMME, AFFAIRE 
WHERE GAMME.GA_DES LIKE 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU' 
  AND GAMME.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF 
  AND AFFAIRE.NAF = 2
```

etc. Because I need to use it in a CASE

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Comment: Also put some sample and expected data.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what you want exactly but I will give you some suggestion:

- Use LIKE with "%" ex. `LIKE '%TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU'` otherwise, use "="
- Instead of `GAMME.NAF= (SELECT A.NAF FROM AFFAIRE A WHERE A.NAF = NAF)` use the JOIN ex. `FROM GAMME inner/outer join AFFAIRE on GAMME.PK = AFFAIRE.FK`
- Read SQL tutorial (this should be the first)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's hard to understand i'll try to be clearer. But for the joins it's because i'm on an internship and people here don't know anything about it so i don't want to bother them with these..

So that's because i need to do something like this

```
(CASE
WHEN AFFAIRE.MODELE = 0 THEN 0
WHEN AFFAIRE.MODELE = 1 THEN 1
WHEN AFFAIRE.MODELE = 2 THEN 2
END)
```

but instead of the 0 I need to get the code i've shown you here (i'll need to change the 1 and 2 later using the same model)

so i have to select the NAF linked to the row like if the NAF is 25 when it's equal to 0 then i have this query as a result

```
SELECT GAMME.GA_NBHR FROM GAMME,AFFAIRE WHERE GAMME.GA_DES LIKE 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU' AND GAMME.NAF = AFFAIRE.NAF AND AFFAIRE.NAF = 25
```

but instead of using a number i need the NAF like it's more like it's a variable

Comment: You can edit the question directly to add more details, don't post the answer for that. Anyways, you can join:
'SELECT 
case when AFFAIRE.NAF = 25 then 'TOURNAGE EBAUCHE ALU'
when AFFAIRE.NAF = xxx then 'YYY'
else 'Default'
FROM GAMME ga inner join AFFAIRE aff on ga.NAF =aff.NAF'